# Programmatically copy index from one table to another, via a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I use a stored procedure to copy the tables from one database to the other database. Right now it does

```
insert into copy 
   select * from original
```

I would like to copy the index from the original table as well. What would be the best way to go about this ?

Comment: Index is not just data - it's a database object. So you're really talking about a vastly different operation - not just copying across data from one table to another, but also **structure** from the old database to the new. This requires you to "inspect" the old index definition and create a new index on the new table to match the old one

Comment: While you can definitely use a stored procedure to move data from old to new, I would *not* recommend doing the same with structural database objects, like tables, indexes, and so on.. if you need them in your new database - script out their definition from the old and run that script **once** on your new table

Comment: +1 @marc_s - You can move data with your `SELECT *` script but you won't catch things like keys, constraints, etc

Comment: @marc_s - I believe replication will also cover all data, constraints, and indexes for a published table.

Comment: What's the impetus for this and how often do you want to do this?  Do the copies need to stay in sync somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a really complicated thing to do in SQL code.  It's complicated because indexes have so many options.  Potential issues/complications:

- Covering indexes
- Included fields
- Column order
- Filtered indexes
- Complicated index types (xml indexes, etc)

You will be much better off either scripting these out in SSMS or using the .NET SMO framework for this.

To appropriately account for all the above issues will require querying a large number of system tables and using `CURSOR`s, `WHILE` loops, or other iterative constructs to get things in the right order.

It ain't pretty.

Comment: Fortunately, I use .net framework and I ended up using the .NET SMO. Thanks for pointing me in right direction.